# Closure compiler app using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify, google-closure-compiler, plovr

I have manage to create a small size js application that uses jQuery and jQuery UI using google's closure compiler with advanced optimizations. Just for clarity: I have not compiled jQuery itself, just my app that uses jquery. I would like to know if somebody can confirm that this idea also works for bigger and more complex apps.

The procedure is as follows:

0.- You have an html file that calls jquery-1.4.3.min.js, test1.js, and test2.js

1.- compile your app and export a property map file

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar \
       --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
       --js test1.js --js test2.js \
       --property_map_output_file prop.out > min.js
```

The property map is a key/value file that contains the name of the property before and after compilation:

```
aprop:a
html:b
each:c
```

2.- Copy prop.out to prop.in and edit it so that jQuery properties (functions) are replaced by the same name (this could be easily automated with a list jquery's function):

```
aprop:a
html:html
each:each
```

3.- Recompile using prop in as property map input

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar \
       --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
       --js test1.js --js test2.js \
       --property_map_input_file prop.in > min.js
```

4.- Now in your html, include min.js and jquery-1.4.3.min.js. The application should be functional but your code should be faster and smaller.

This will minify your code, not jquery's.

As I said, I have tested this in a small app. If somebody has a bigger and complex app, it would be nice to know that this works.

Thanks,

heg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [externs](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html). As far as I know that is the way to go to keep the jQuery methods from being shortened in your code. [Externs for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn/trunk/contrib/externs) exist as contributions to the closure project.

For jQuery UI you might want to try [this](http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/). It is something I came across once but haven't tested it myself

BTW: If you're interested, there is this extremely handy build tool for closure: [Plovr](http://plovr.com/). I use it all the time and I made externs work with it.

Comment: I tried using externs (with the normal jquery js) without success. I was not aware of "Externs for jQuery". Looks promising but I will still need to do something with jQuery UI.

Thanks for the info about plovr!